# Mobile app backend using Gin and Gorm ORM

Tags: mysql, go, web-services, twitter, rest

I'm developing backend for my mobile app by using gin-gonic and gorm ORM (mysql). But I'm not sure api and db handle huge amount requests if clients increased. for example I'm using my db struct as parameter, is this a problem for concurrency ?

Here is my implementation:

`main.go`:

```
var i Impl

func main() {

    // #GIN# //
    r := gin.New()
    r.Use(gin.Logger())
    r.Use(gin.Recovery())
    // #GIN# //

    // #DB# //
    i.InitDB()
    // #DB# //

    // #TWITTER# //
    t := Twitter{}
    t.InitTwitter()
    // #TWITTER# //

    r.GET("/someEndpoint", func(c *gin.Context) {
    i.InsertUser(&user)
    go t.Ping(&i)
    c.JSON(200, gin.H{"status": true})
    })

    r.Run(":5000")
}
```

`twitter.go`:

```
// InitAPI TO-DO
func (t *Twitter) InitAPI(token string, tokenSecret string) {
    t.API = anaconda.NewTwitterApi(token, tokenSecret)
    t.UserID = strings.Split(token, "-")[0]
}

// Ping TO-DO
func (t *Twitter) Ping(i *Impl) {
    t.GetHomeTimeLine(i)
    t.GetUsersFriends(i)
}

// GetHomeTimeLine TO-DO
func (t *Twitter) GetHomeTimeLine(i *Impl) {
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("count", "200")
    v.Set("exclude_replies", "true")
    results, err := t.API.GetHomeTimeline(v)

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }

    tweets := convertTweets(results, t.UserID)
    go i.CreateOrUpdateTimeline(tweets)
}

// GetUsersFriends TO-DO
func (t *Twitter) GetUsersFriends(i *Impl) {
    v := url.Values{}
    v.Set("count", "200")
    v.Set("skip_status", "true")
    friendsChannel := t.API.GetFriendsListAll(v)

    for {
        _friends, more := <-friendsChannel
        if _friends.Error != nil {
            log.Println(_friends.Error.Error())
            break
        }

        friends := convertFriends(_friends.Friends, t.UserID)
        go i.CreateOrUpdateFriends(friends)
        if !more {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

`db.go`:

```
// Impl TO-DO
type Impl struct {
    DB gorm.DB
}

// InitDB TO-DO
func (i *Impl) InitDB() {
    var err error
    i.DB, err = gorm.Open("mysql", "connection string")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Got error when connect database, the error is '%v'", err)
    }
    i.DB.LogMode(false)
    i.DB.DB().SetMaxIdleConns(10)
    i.DB.DB().SetMaxOpenConns(100)
}

// InsertUser TO-DO
func (i *Impl) InsertUser(user *User) bool {
    if err := i.DB.Create(&user).Error; err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("InsertError: %s", err.Error())
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```